# Access textfield of UIAlertController - swift ios8

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I'm trying to access the text field of a UIAlertView and I'm using the `textFields` property and I get the following output from the `textFields` property:

```
<_UIAlertControllerTextField: 0x7fe911f96790; 
frame = (4 4; 231 16);  
text = 'THIS IS THE TEXT THAT I JUST ENTERED';  
clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO;  
gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7fe914215cc0>;  
layer = <CALayer: 0x7fe911f96c40>>
```

As you can see the text does show up, but I need the text separately. `textFields.text` won't work because its deprecated and cannot be used in Swift.

Comment: Can u post more Code? You can access your textfield with: let textField = alert.textFieldAtIndex(0)

Comment: Yeah, could you post the code where you grab the text field and `println` it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The textFields are stored in an Array of AnyObject. If you want to access text you should cast it as a UITextField first:

```
((alert.textFields[0] as UITextField).text)
```

Comment: `'[AnyObject]?' does not have a member named 'subscript'` so use `!` before `[0]`