# UIAlert w/ text field to table

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, ios8

My objective is to create a new row in the table in the master view titled with the input from the UIAlert stored in `namePrompt`. How would I achieve this?

Currently, when I try to make a new row (using the `+` button in the top-right hand corner of the iPad simulator, running iOS 8) it crashes the app. I'm not really sure what I have done wrong, and any help at all is appreciated.

Code:

```
func insertNewObject(sender: AnyObject) {
//prompt for kid name
var namePrompt = UIAlertController(title: "Add Child", message: "Please enter child name", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
namePrompt.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil))
namePrompt.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Add Child", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
namePrompt.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({(textField: UITextField!) in
textField.placeholder = "Johnny"
})
self.presentViewController(namePrompt, animated: true, completion: nil)

let childName: AnyObject = namePrompt.textFields![0]

//add new object w/ above name
objects.insertObject(childName, atIndex: 0)
let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
}
```

I think that the problem is arising from the `let childName: Any Object` line, and/or the `objects.insertObject` line.

--**EDIT**--

When I build/run the project, no errors are given to me in the code, but when I try to add a new row, as soon as I press the `+` button, I get `0x1fbaff4:  nopw   %cs:(%eax,%eax)` from `Thread 1` . This is related to the line `let object = objects[indexPath.row] as NSDate` (in below snippet) line (the default for the `objects.insertObject` line above was an NSDAte). I changed the `NSDate` to `NSString` and the same thing happened.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    let object = objects[indexPath.row] as NSString
    cell.textLabel?.text = object.description
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Update your question with details about the crash including the full error message and pointing out which line is causing the crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be assuming that the textFields of the UIAlertController will be filled in immediately after the alert is presented. That doesn't give the user any time to actually fill out the fields.

Put the `let childName = namePrompt.textFields![0]` line (and following) in one of your button actions instead and wait for the user to tap that button before reading the textField.

**--EDIT--**

Here is your code with my suggested modification. I made as few changes to your code as possible. Note that there is an if statement to guard against empty childNames, but it won't guard against someone entering a bunch of spaces. You should probably make that part more robust.

```
func insertNewObject(sender: AnyObject) {
    //prompt for kid name
    var namePrompt = UIAlertController(title: "Add Child", message: "Please enter child name", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    namePrompt.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil))
    namePrompt.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Add Child", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (alertAction) in
        let childName = (namePrompt.textFields![0] as UITextField).text as String
        if childName != "" {
            self.objects.insert(childName, atIndex: 0)
            let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
            self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
        }
    }))
    namePrompt.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({(textField: UITextField!) in
        textField.placeholder = "Johnny"
    })
    self.presentViewController(namePrompt, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: In the `handler` spot of the `addAction` for 'Add Child'?

Comment: That makes sense. You likely don't want to read the value until after the user tap the add child button, right?

Comment: I replaced `insertNewObject` function with the above code (thank you), and the UIAlert opened correctly, but when I press `Add Child`, the UIAlert goes away, the keyboard stays shown, and no new row is added. Any idea why?

Comment: It also gave me `0x2052ff4:  nopw   %cs:(%eax,%eax)` in the Thread 1 debugger (or what I assume to be a debugger?)

Comment: The problem is that textFields[0] is not a String, it is a UITextField. You have to dig deeper to get to the actual text. I will edit the above answer.

Comment: FYI, I referenced this SO question to help find the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25068620/access-textfield-of-uialertcontroller-swift-ios8

Comment: The line where the name was added to the NSMutableArray had an error; it should be `self.objects.insertObject`, not `self.objects.insert`. I added the edit, it's currently under peer review.

Comment: @techgod52 My assumption was that `objects` is a Swift Array rather than an NSMutableArray. Thus it uses `insert` rather than `insertObject`.